# How to prevent the app from getting paused when killed in ionic 2

Tags: android, ios, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an app in which a function will get called every minute (calling the function every minute is done through **setinterval** method).I have also implemented the local notificaiton inside  this function.So after every minute it will call the function and it will show the notification.I am able to see the notification after every minute and this happens only when the app is running or when it is minimized ,but when i close the app this function is not getting called. I've used background mode plugin but that is not working when the app is killed or cleared.

code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';
import {BackgroundMode} from '@ionic-native/background-mode';
import {Http,RequestOptions,Headers} from '@angular/http'
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  count:any;
content= "Yashwanth"
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public http: Http,public backgroundMode: BackgroundMode,private localNotifications: LocalNotifications) {

 this.backgroundMode.enable();
  }
a(){
   let body:string ="&a=aksjd",
    url:any = "http://some_site_name/abc.php",    
    type : string   = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    headers  : any      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': type}),
    options  : any      = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    this.http.post(url,body,options).subscribe((data) => {
      let a = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
      this.count = a['count'];
    console.log(this.count);

        this.localNotifications.schedule({
  id: 1,
  text: 'The count of ' + this.content + this.count

});

    });
setInterval(()=>this.a(),60000);
}

ionViewDidLoad(){
this.a();
}

}
```